# gsub not considering ? (question mark) while executing

Tags: r

I am trying to execute the below code

```
library(purrr)
library(glue)
library(tidyquant)

gsub("https://abc.a/:x:/s/asd/esdfgy?=jo", " % s ", "This is the link https://abc.a/:x:/s/asd/esdfgy=jo")
[1] "This is the link  % s "
```

Above execution is correct.
But when I include ? in my text the output is different. Can i have a same output like above?

```
gsub("https://abc.a/:x:/s/asd/esdfgy?=jo", " % s ", "This is the link https://abc.a/:x:/s/asd/esdfgy?=jo")
[1] "This is the link https://abc.a/:x:/s/asd/esdfgy?=jo"
```

Expected output

```
[1] "This is the link  % s "
```

Comment: `?` has a special meaning in regex. Use `\\?`. `gsub("https://abc.a/:x:/s/asd/esdfgy\\?=jo", " % s ", "This is the link https://abc.a/:x:/s/asd/esdfgy?=jo")`

Comment: But I am trying to replace ? with //? with this code ````str_replace("sdsdsz?","?","\\?")```` but not happening?

Comment: why do you want to replace `?` with `?` and you need to escape the pattern and not replacement. Try `str_replace("sdsdsz?","\\?","!")`

Comment: as you mentioned use ````\\?````.  So when I have ? , I will replace with \\?. But your suggestion is not working ````str_replace("sdsdsz?","\\?","!")````

Comment: Hope you got my point :)

Comment: So basically ````This is the link https://abc.a/:x:/s/asd/esdfgy?=jo```` is the link, We cannot escape ? here and it will be a invalid url. So only